# Set JLabel to top of JTextArea and move down JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, jtextarea

I have a small GUI contains JPanel in which have got JTextArea and JLabel, when I make

```
panel1.setLayout(null);
```

I can get the required position done but JTextArea disappearing! when I make

```
panel1.setLayout((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

I can get both [Jlabel and JTextArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giUe6.png) visible but couldn't able to get the position, How to get the required position set, am newbie! help please! thanks

Code:

```
private void createPageScreen1() {
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    //panel1.setLayout(null);
    //panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    JLabel lblProcessingData = new JLabel();
    //lblProcessingData.setBounds(5, 5, 15, 10);
    lblProcessingData.setLocation(5, 5);
    lblProcessingData.setText("label for Title");
    panel1.add(lblProcessingData);

    String fileName = "loadFiles\\testFile.txt";

    try {
        textArea = new JTextArea(40, 37);
        //textArea.setBounds(5, 20, 40, 37);
        textArea.setBorder (new TitledBorder (new EtchedBorder(), fileName));
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setVisible(true);

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        textArea.read(br, null);
        br.close();
        textArea.requestFocus();

        JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy (ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        panel1.add(scroll1);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    panel1.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 2):

For this type of program, file content display and a label, the BorderLayout suites better.

```
private void createPageScreen1()
{
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    // Use BorderLayout
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel lblProcessingData = new JLabel();
    lblProcessingData.setText("label for Title");
    // Add Label to top
    lblProcessingData.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    panel1.add(lblProcessingData, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    String fileName = "loadFiles\\testFile.txt";

    try
    {
        textArea = new JTextArea(40, 37);
        textArea.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), fileName));
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setVisible(true);

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        textArea.read(br, null);
        br.close();
        textArea.requestFocus();

        JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        // Fill remaining space with TextArea
        panel1.add(scroll1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    panel1.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wladimir82,  when I change it to `panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` I get the [output](http://i.imgur.com/qPCxN1a.png) like this, can't see the label!

Comment: Don't forget to add the components with the Layout constraints like "panel1.add(lblProcessingData, BorderLayout.NORTH);"

Comment: You should not set any 'bounds' too, since the layout manager will do that for you. But I see that you solved the problem with a 'TitledBorder' :)

Comment: Thanks @Wladimir82, I did not set any bounds! the title border comes from `textArea.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), fileName));` this!